# Wordpress on Lightsail working slow when uploading through FTP

Tags: wordpress, amazon-lightsail

I recently migrated my site to lightsail. My db has about 2mm records and slightly under 1Gb. I connected do the DB through an external client. While I was connected but not running any queries, site became slow.
Then I tried uploading some images through FTP, at that point, the site came to a halt again, would even open.
Upon looking at metrics, I got into burstable zone here and there, but its not sustained.

Any there tools I can use to diagnose what is the problem.

Comment: I noticed the same issue. I am using a 2 GB RAM, 1 vCPU, 60 GB SSD WordPress site using the default bitnami package. Average CPU utilization never went over 3.7%. Maybe it has to do with the fact that I am connecting using sftp on port 22.

Answer (score 0):

What size instance did you deploy? Also, is this Linux or Windows. It would be good to look at metrics from the lightsail dashboard but also be good to know what's running inside of your instance. I'd be curious to know if you are overburdening your instance (undersized) or not.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Answer (score 0):

SFTP is generally slower than FTP due to the security built into the protocol. The data is encrypted, which takes time, but perhaps more importantly, the protocol itself functions differently; it's not "streamed" like FTP.